# Forcing empty rows from query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table containing monthly statistics for clients.
Columns are CustNo, Year, Month, Trips

Some customers do not have any trips in some months and therefore there are combinations of CustNo, Year and Month that have no rows in that table.

I am trying to write a Query that shows 0 for those combinations of CustNo, Year and Month that have no trips, instead of producing an empty row.

To start with I have created a ValidPeriods table that has a Year and a Month column containing those periods that are valid. 
I can then Query like this:

```
SELECT v.ValidYear, v.ValidMonth, tc.CustNo, tc.Trips
FROM ValidPeriods v 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TempTrips AS tc ON v.ValidYear = tc.Year 
                AND v.ValidMonth = tc.Month
WHERE tc.CustNo IN (1001230, 1001286, 1001292)
```

This will give me rows for all periods, with 1 row with NULL values for those periods where there are no customers in the list that have any trips.

But how do I get one row for each customer in the list for all periods?

Ideally I want this:

```
2016  1  1001230  0
2016  1  1001286  14
2016  1  1001292  23
2016  2  1001230  7
2016  2  1001286  0
2016  2  1001292  4
```

etc...

Comment: What does `temptrips` look like?

Comment: TempTrips is the table I am mentioning at first in the post. Columns are CustNo, Year, Month, Trips

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generate the rows using `cross join`.  Then fill in the values using `left join`:

```
SELECT ym.ValidYear, ym.ValidMonth, c.CustNo, COALESCE(tt.Trips, 0)
FROM ValidPeriods ym CROSS JOIN
     (VALUES (1001230), (1001286), (1001292)) c(CustNo) LEFT JOIN
     TempTrips tt
     ON tt.ValidYear = ym.ValidYear AND tt.ValidMOnth = ym.ValidMonth AND
        tt.CustNo = c.CustNo;
```